# How do I get Sphinx to test code embedded in documentation?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

If this code is a blockquote in my documentation, what do I need to do to make [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) run it when the documentation is generated? I tried adding

```
.. testcode::

    import datetime
    def today():
        return datetime.datetime.now().date()
    if True:
        today()
```

to one of the `.rst` sources and the Sphinx doctest extension to `conf.py`, but I got an error complaining about unexpected indentation on the first line of the function body. Is Sphinx's doctest able to run functions defined in the documentation?

Comment: Did you read http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/doctest.html? What *specific* questions did you have based on what your read?

Comment: Since testblock is not a Sphinx directive, I have no idea what you think is supposed to happen.  If you meant `testcode`, you're missing the the `testoutput`.  If you meant `doctest`, you're missing all the expected punctuation.

Comment: If .. testcode:: won't run without .. testoutput:: then that's a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `testcode` directive needs a matching `testoutput` directive.

Here's the example from the documentation.

```
.. testcode::

   print 'Output     text.'

.. testoutput::
   :hide:
   :options: -ELLIPSIS, +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE

   Output text.
```